# How to make photoshop/illustrator ONE panel and not split into many?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop

This is really annoying me, and no google search got me anywhere. How to make it look normal as one program with the black background as usual?

not like this:
[image: not like this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in `Window` menu: `Application Frame` and this only exists on MacOS.

Comment: yes amazing! the whole studio couldn't figure it out, thanks